# Divide a grid into several possibilities

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, time-complexity

A grid of size m*n is provided with numbers 1, 2, 3 only, where m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns.

Divide the grid into two parts either horizontally or vertically such that each division must contain at least one cell with value 2. Once divided we can further divide to get other combinations.
Find how many divisions are possible for given grid values.

For example, if the input grid:

```
1,2,3
2,1,2
3,1,1
```

**Output is** `4`.

**Below are the 4 possibilities.**

```
Possibility (1)
 1,2,3
-------
 2,1,2
 3,1,1
 
  |
2,|1,2
3,|1,1
  |
  
Possibility (2)
  
 1,2,3
-------
 2,1,2
 3,1,1
    
    |
2,1,|2
3,1,|1
    |
Possibility (3)
  |
1,|2,3
2,|1,2
3,|1,1
  |
 
  | 
2,|3
1,|2
1,|1  
  |
  
Possibility (4) 
  |
1,|2,3
2,|1,2
3,|1,1
  |
 
 2,3
-----
 1,2
 1,1
```

How to solve this efficiently in terms of runtime complexity.

As a first step, I have modified the grid by setting the value to 0 when an element is 1 or 3. Then set the value to 1 when an element is 2. So I have converted it to a binary matrix. But I am not able to find a way to get the possible combinations.

```
public int process(int[][] grid) {
   int m = grid.length, n = grid[0].length;
   int result = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
         int e = grid[i][j];
         if(e == 2) grid[i][j] = 1;
         else grid[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }
   //.....todo...
   return result;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, even if you regard it as inefficient?

Comment: How far can you keep dividing?  Seems to me that answer #1 could continue to divide the 2x2 grid.  And if you can keep dividing, what is the smallest grid that can't be divided?  1x1, or 1x2 and 2x1, or what?

Comment: Also, when you say 'efficiently' do you mean from a programming perspective, or from a runtime perspective?

Comment: @DavidA, I updated the post with required information now

Comment: Off topic: I  don't yet see how converting it to a binary matrix helps. There isn't going to be much difference in `if (mat [i][j] ==2)`, `if (mat [i][j] == 1)`, or `if (mat [i][j])` where `mat` is `int [][]` in the first two, and `boolean [][]` in the third.

Comment: If a matrix contains no cell with value `2`, what should the result be?  If it contains exactly 1 cell with value `2`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sur I understand your question fully, but here are my two cents:

Start by defining a method that checks that a subgrid contains at least one 2:

```
public static boolean contains2(int[][] grid, int rs, int re, int cs, int ce) {
    for (int i = rs; i < re; i++) {
        for (int j = cs; j < ce; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] == 2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Next, you can define a method returning the number of possible horizontal splits of a subgrid:

```
public static int splitCountH(int[][] grid, int rs, int re, int cs, int ce) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = rs+1; i < re; ++i) {
        if (contains2(grid, rs, i, cs, ce) && contains2(grid, i, re, cs, ce)) {
            ++result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and another one giving the number of possible vertical splits:

```
public static int splitCountV(int[][] grid, int rs, int re, int cs, int ce) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int j = cs+1; j < ce; ++j) {
        if (contains2(grid, rs, re, cs, j) && contains2(grid, rs, re, j, ce)) {
            ++result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Next method gives the number of possible combinations of a horizontal split followed by a vertical split or a vertical split followed by a horizontal split:

```
public static int process(int[][] grid, int rs, int re, int cs, int ce) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = rs+1; i < re; ++i) {
        if (contains2(grid, rs, i, cs, ce) && contains2(grid, i, re, cs, ce)) {
            result += splitCountV(grid, rs, i, cs, ce)
                    + splitCountV(grid, i, re, cs, ce);
        }
    }
    for (int j = cs+1; j < ce; ++j) {
        if (contains2(grid, rs, re, cs, j) && contains2(grid, rs, re, j, ce)) {
            result += splitCountH(grid, rs, re, cs, j)
                    + splitCountH(grid, rs, re, j, ce);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your process method becomes:

```
public static int process(int[][] grid) {
    return process(grid, 0, grid.length, 0, grid[0].length);
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want to authorize two horizontal splits or two vertical splits, you can add the following method:

```
public static int splitCount(int[][] grid, int rs, int re, int cs, int ce) {
    return splitCountH(grid, rs, re, cs, ce)
            + splitCountV(grid, rs, re, cs, ce);
}
```

And modify the `process` method:

```
public static int process(int[][] grid, int rs, int re, int cs, int ce) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = rs+1; i < re; ++i) {
        if (contains2(grid, rs, i, cs, ce) && contains2(grid, i, re, cs, ce)) {
            result += splitCount(grid, rs, i, cs, ce)
                    + splitCount(grid, i, re, cs, ce);
        }
    }
    for (int j = cs+1; j < ce; ++j) {
        if (contains2(grid, rs, re, cs, j) && contains2(grid, rs, re, j, ce)) {
            result += splitCount(grid, rs, re, cs, j)
                    + splitCount(grid, rs, re, j, ce);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But in this case, you would have 6 possibilities for your example.

Comment: @greybeard OK, I have updated my answer to support two vertical splits or two horizontal splits, but in this case there are 6 possibilities.

Comment: (6 distinct sequences of divisions/splits leading to five distinct configurations of "single-2-parts": What *is* one *possibility*?)

Comment: True, and it's both five distinct configurations of single-2-parts and five distinct division-drawings in that case (ignoring the order they are drawn in). But for a 2x2 grid filled by 2s there is only one configuration of single-2-parts, but two different division-drawings (horizontal or vertical unbroken).

Answer (score 1):

> **Below are the 4 possibilities.**
>
> ```
>  (1)    (2)    (3)    (4)
>
> 1 2 3  1 2 3  1|2|3  1|2 3
> -----  -----   | |    |---
> 2|1 2  2 1|2  2|1|2  2|1 2
>  |        |    | |    |
> 3|1 1  3 1|1  3|1|1  3|1 1
> ```

What about

```
 (V)

1 2|3
---| 
2 1|2
   | 
3 1|1
```

?

```
 (VI)  (VII)  (VIII)
1 2 3  1 2|3  1|2 3
-----     |    |
2 1 2  2 1|2  2|1 2
          |    |
3 1 1  3 1|1  3|1 1
```

? *each division must contain **at least** one cell with value 2*

Comment: *"Specification" by example* is error-prone.

Comment: We have to divide horizontally then next sub divisions. Otherwise divide it vertically then sub divisions. In that case we can get only 4 possibilities. The new combination mentioned here is not valid one.

Comment: "The new combination" is first divide vertically in two left columns and one right column, containing a single 2 and not divisible any further. Then divide the two left columns into a top row and a two-by-two "bottom" sub-matrix. It is to "possibility (4)" what 2 is to 1. Every part shown contains a 2. *How* would this combination be *not* valid? If it is invalid, and you don't find the *why* in the question, please add it *there*.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is going to be your friend here.  Sorry I did this in Python instead of Java, but the algorithm will be the same.  Essentially, divide the grid and test to see if there's a 2 on either side.  If there is, recurse each side until there's not.

```py
import itertools

grid = [ 1, 2, 3
       , 2, 1, 2
       , 3, 1, 1 ]
    
def print_horz( top, trows, bottom, brows, columns, depth ):
    for m in range( trows ):
        print( '    ' * depth, top[ m * columns : ( m + 1 ) * columns ] )
    print( '    ' * depth, '-' * columns )
    for m in range( brows ):
        print( '    ' * depth, bottom[ m * columns : ( m + 1 ) * columns ] )
    print()
    
def print_vert( left, lcolumns, right, rcolumns, rows, depth ):
    for m in range( rows ):
        print( '    ' * depth
            , left[ m * lcolumns : ( m + 1 ) * lcolumns ]
            , '|'
            , right[ m * rcolumns : ( m + 1 ) * rcolumns ] )
    print()
    
def divide_grid( grid, rows, columns, depth = 0 ):
    if grid.count( 2 ) < 2:
        return
    
    #print( '    ' * depth, 'grid', grid, depth )
    for m in range( rows - 1 ):
        top = grid[ : ( m + 1 ) * columns ]
        bottom = grid[ ( m + 1 ) * columns : ]
        #print( '    ' * depth, 'horz {}/{}/{}'.format( m, rows - 1, depth), top, ( m + 1 ), bottom, rows - ( m + 1 ), columns )
        if 2 in top and 2 in bottom:
            print_horz( top, ( m + 1 ), bottom, rows - ( m + 1 ), columns, depth )
    
            divide_grid( top, ( m + 1 ), columns, depth + 1 )
            divide_grid( bottom, rows - ( m + 1 ), columns, depth + 1 )
    
    for n in range( columns - 1 ):
        left = list( itertools.chain.from_iterable(
            [ grid[ m * columns : ( m + 1 ) * columns ][ : ( n + 1 ) ] for m in range( rows ) ] ) )
        right = list( itertools.chain.from_iterable(
            [ grid[ m * columns : ( m + 1 ) * columns ][ ( n + 1 ) : ] for m in range( rows ) ] ) )
        #print( '    ' * depth, 'vert {}/{}/{}'.format( n, columns - 1, depth), left, ( n + 1 ), right, columns - ( n + 1 ), rows )
        if 2 in left and 2 in right:
            print_vert( left, ( n + 1 ), right, columns - ( n + 1 ), rows, depth )
    
            divide_grid( left, rows, ( n + 1 ), depth + 1 )
            divide_grid( right, rows, columns - ( n + 1 ), depth + 1 )
    
divide_grid( grid, 3, 3 )
```

Results

```
 [1, 2, 3]
 ---
 [2, 1, 2]
 [3, 1, 1]

     [2] | [1, 2]
     [3] | [1, 1]

     [2, 1] | [2]
     [3, 1] | [1]

 [1] | [2, 3]
 [2] | [1, 2]
 [3] | [1, 1]

     [2, 3]
     --
     [1, 2]
     [1, 1]

     [2] | [3]
     [1] | [2]
     [1] | [1]

 [1, 2] | [3]
 [2, 1] | [2]
 [3, 1] | [1]

     [1, 2]
     --
     [2, 1]
     [3, 1]

     [1] | [2]
     [2] | [1]
     [3] | [1]
```

Comment: So, *how many divisions are possible for given grid values* in this example?

Comment: Depends on how you count it. The original question isn’t super clear on what counts. Do you count divisions that could then be sub divided or only unique patterns once all divisions have been made?

Comment: I [tried for a week](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74025972/3789665) to get the question improved there. My money would be on 5 for the equivalence of the "single column possibilities" arrived at in two different sequences.